# Laravel: Build tree structure with endless childs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Heey all im trying to build a tree structure with endless childs with Laravel.

This is what i use for building the tree:

```
$result = '';
    foreach($categories as $root) {

        $result .= sprintf('
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="parent_id" id="" value="%d">
                            %s
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>', $root->id, $root->title
        );

        if(isset($root->children)) {
            $this->getChildren($root->children, $result);
        }

    }

    dd($result);
```

As you see im referring to another method inside my method.
That one looks like this:

```
public function getChildren($children, $result)
    {
        foreach($children as $child) {
            $result .= sprintf('
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="parent_id" id="" value="%d">
                                %s
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>', $child->id, $child->title
            );

            if(isset($child->children)) {
                $this->getChildren($child->children, $result);
            }

        }

        return $result;


    }
```

However this is only returning my main result..

How can i keep appending data to the $result variable?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for code duplication, simply:

```
$result = $this->getChildren($categories);

dd($result);
```

And

```
public function getChildren($children)
{
    $result = '';
    foreach($children as $child) {
        $result .= sprintf('
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="parent_id" id="" value="%d">
                            %s
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>', $child->id, $child->title
        );

        if(isset($child->children)) {
            $result .= $this->getChildren($child->children);
        }

    }

    return $result;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your function declaration to:

```
public function getChildren($children, &$result)
```

The `&` sign means that you are passing the variable by reference.